# Custom Font is not loading in application in Swift

Tags: swift, fonts, build, custom-font

I added a ttf file to my XCode folder, added the application as target membership, checked that it is in *Build Phase/Copy Bundle Resources*, and added it to `info.plist` as **"YanoljaYachae.ttf".**

When I try to use it in storyboard, it works fine. I can see it in custom/fonts and when I use the font it appears in the storyboard. However, when I build the application in either my phone or in the virtual device, the font would not load.

Do you have any clue why this is not working?

Comment: have you tried checking https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/ ??